# Found markup element with unexpected name 'EditForm'

Tags: blazor-server-side

Running VS2019 16.8.0, .Net SDK from 3.1.302 to 5.0.100 - Blazor Server project

I have a razor form and the compiler does not recognize 'EditForm', 'InputText' etc.

Here is the code:

```
page "/GetCustomerProfile"
@using QuoteBL.Data
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1>Please fill out form</h1>

<EditForm Model="srcfields" OnValidSubmit="@InvokeGetQuote">

    <p>
        <label for="age">Age:</label>
        <InputText id="age" @bind-Value="QuoteBLModel.age1" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="smoke">Do you smoke?</label>
        <InputCheckbox id="smoke" @bind-Value="AllFieldsModel.smoker" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>
            Sex:
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="QuoteBLModel.sex1">
                <option value="Select Sex"></option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </InputSelect>
        </label>
    </p>

</EditForm>

<div>
    <span id="resultjson"></span>
</div>

@code {

    private AllFieldsModel scrfields = new AllFieldsModel();

    private async Task InvokeGetQuote()
    {

// await etc...

    }
}
```

=================================
Model has 2 classes

```
namespace QuoteBL.Models
{
    public class QuoteBLModel
    {
        public static string productLine = "QoLFlexTerm";
        public static string display = "101";
        public static string state = "";
        public static string sex1 = "";
        public static string age1 = "";
        public static string face_Amount = "";
        public static string premMode = "3";
        public static string flatAmount1 = "0";
        public static string tableRating1 = "0";
        public static string command = "submit";
    }
    public class AllFieldsModel
    {
        public static string CustPhone = "";
        public static string CustEmail = "";
        public static string age1 = "";
        public static string sex1 = "";
        public static string state = "";
        public static bool   smoker = false;
        public static string name = "";
        public static string address = "";
        public static string city = "";
        public static string state = "";
        public static string zip = "";
        public static string loan = "";
        public static string agentPhone = "";
        public static string agentEmail = "";
}
```

====

I know that I must be doing something wrong. The answers that I saw pertained to a different situation.

Help is appreciated

Comment: Are you adding the appropriate using statements in your imports file?  Specifically Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

Comment: Here is the _imports.razor:`@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json 
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using QuoteBL
@using QuoteBL.Shared
@using QuoteBL.Models`
I also deleted the .vs folder as suggested for a similar problem...